# How to pass speech to text field in flutter?

Tags: flutter, dart, input, text, textfield

I have an application in Flutter that translates speech to text, the problem is that I have not found a way to put the results in input or a `TextField` in Flutter, so far it only transcribes to text which cannot (obviously) be modified. How to put the results in a `TextField`?

This is my code:

```html
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:speech_to_text/speech_to_text.dart' as stt;

class SpeechScreen extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  _SpeechScreenState createState() => _SpeechScreenState();
}

class _SpeechScreenState extends State<SpeechScreen> {
  stt.SpeechToText _speech;
  bool _isListening = false;
  String _textSpeech = 'Presiona el botón para iniciar a hablar';

  void onListen() async {
    bool available = await _speech.initialize(
        onStatus: (val) => print('onStatus: $val'),
        onError: (val) => print('onError: $val'));

    if (!_isListening) {
      if (available) {
        setState(() {
          _isListening = false;
          _speech.listen(
            onResult: (val) => setState(() {
              _textSpeech = val.recognizedWords;
            }),
          );
        });
      }
    } else {
      setState(() {
        _isListening = false;
        _speech.stop();
      });
    }
  }

  void stopListen() {
    _speech.stop();
    setState(() {});
  }

  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    _speech = stt.SpeechToText();
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    _fondoApp() {
      final gradiente = Container(
        width: double.infinity,
        height: double.infinity,
        decoration: BoxDecoration(
            gradient: LinearGradient(
                begin: FractionalOffset(0.0, 0.0),
                end: FractionalOffset(0.0, 1.0),
                colors: [Colors.black87, Colors.black])),
      );

      return Stack(
        children: <Widget>[gradiente],
      );
    }

    return Scaffold(
        body: Stack(children: <Widget>[
          _fondoApp(),
          Container(
              padding: EdgeInsets.all(30.0),
              child: Text(_textSpeech,
                  style: TextStyle(
                      fontSize: 32,
                      color: Colors.white,
                      fontWeight: FontWeight.w500))),
        ]),
        floatingActionButtonLocation: FloatingActionButtonLocation.centerFloat,
        floatingActionButton: Padding(
          padding: const EdgeInsets.all(8.0),
          child: Row(
            mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
            children: <Widget>[
              FloatingActionButton(
                onPressed: onListen,
                child: Icon(Icons.mic),
                backgroundColor: Colors.green,
              ),
              SizedBox(
                width: 40,
              ),
              SizedBox(
                child: _speech.isListening
                    ? Text(
                        "Escuchando...",
                        style: TextStyle(
                            color: Colors.white, fontWeight: FontWeight.bold),
                      )
                    : Text(
                        'Sin escuchar',
                        style: TextStyle(
                            color: Colors.white, fontWeight: FontWeight.bold),
                      ),
              ),
              SizedBox(
                width: 40,
              ),
              FloatingActionButton(
                child: Icon(Icons.stop),
                heroTag: "btn2",
                backgroundColor: Colors.redAccent,
                onPressed: () => stopListen(),
              ),
            ],
          ),
        ));
  }
}
```

Your help would really be amazing, thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We can create a `TextField` with a `TextEditingController`:

```
class _SpeechScreenState extends State<SpeechScreen> {
   TextEditingControlller _textEditingController = TextEditingControlller();

   Widget _buildTextController() {
      return TextField(controller: _textEditingController);
   }
}
```

By doing so, after we translate the speech to text, we can update the `_textEditingController` text:

```
  void onListen() async {
    bool available = await _speech.initialize(
        onStatus: (val) => print('onStatus: $val'),
        onError: (val) => print('onError: $val'));

    if (!_isListening) {
      if (available) {
        setState(() {
          _isListening = false;
          _speech.listen(
            onResult: (val) => setState(() {
              _textSpeech = val.recognizedWords;
              _textEditingController.text = val.recognizedWords; 
            }),
          );
        });
      }
    } else {
      setState(() {
        _isListening = false;
        _speech.stop();
      });
    }
  }
```

Comment: what if we have multiple fields with multiple controllers?